# Is a terminating forward slash technically appropriate when specifying a URL?

Tags: internet, browser, web, url, uri

Most web browsers will allow the user to specify:

`https://superuser.com/`

or

`https://superuser.com`

But which is technically appropriate, and why?

Answer (score 3):

Forward slash in URI/URL specification is a separator between the host (or host+port) part and the path.

It is not strictly enforced if the path is not present I the URL.

The first definition in [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) states that in case of an URL use for HTML:

> An HTTP URL takes the form:
>
> ```
>  http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>
> ```

> [ ]

> If neither  nor  is present, the "/"
> may also be omitted.

Later [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) provides a more detailed guidance towards treating the URL with and without the trailing slash as equivalent:

> because the "http" scheme [ ] defines an empty path to be equivalent to "/", the following four URIs are equivalent:
>
> ```
>  http://example.com
>  http://example.com/
>  http://example.com:/
>  http://example.com:80/
> ```

Following the RFC guidelines, including the `/` is adhering to the strict form, while omitting it is allowed.